# Array in scala produced by x to y by z resulting in long decimals

Tags: scala, bigdecimal

I am trying to generate a Numeric Range of Double by `val arrayOfDoubles = (0.0 to 1.0 by 0.1).toArray`, but the resultant is not what I expected it to be. the result is something like `Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999)`. Why is it like this. I could use this code to get what I expect it to be:

```
val roundedArray = for (x <- arrayOfDoubles) yield  BigDecimal(x).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
```

Which results in `Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)`But this looks really cumbersome and expensive for BigDecimal converts the double to String and then parse it.

Is there a way I could get the NumericRange already rounded to one decimal place?

Thanks.

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0 to 10 map (_ / 10.0)
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please edit it to `0 to 10 map (_.toDouble / 10)` because your code produces Vector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), so I could accept it as an answer. I tried to edit this answer, but for some strange reason it was rejected.

Comment: Note the division is by 10.0 which results in double scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact, i.e. some decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly, and are represented by the closest available numbers. See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)